# How do I get an array of pointers to a structures?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I need to create an array of head pointers.

```
typedef struct data_{
  void *data;
  struct data_ *next;
}data;

typedef struct buckets_{
  data *data;
  void *key;
}buckets;

typedef struct hash_table_ {
  buckets **buckets_array;
} hash_table, *Phash_table;

Phash_table table_p;
table_p = (void *)malloc(sizeof(hash_table));
table_p -> buckets_array = (void **)malloc(sizeof(buckets buckets)*size); 
/*Line #7*/
```

When I tried to compile I get this

```
hash.c:7:62: error: expected ')' before 'buckets'
hash.c:7:28: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

I'm trying to get an array of buckets and each bucket will point to a linked list.
Am I on the right path?

Comment: `sizeof(buckets buckets)` - you've written `buckets` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. I think you wanted to write

```
table_p -> buckets_array = (void **)malloc(sizeof(buckets)*size);
```

Comment: Nvm that (void **) was causing the problem. Thanks for the help.